# How to prevent compilers from "optimizing" SIMD constants to lookup tables?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86, clang, simd

An example is probably best here, so consider [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Tbq9x1rr8) code (ignore the logic, it's nonsense):

```
#include <emmintrin.h>

auto foo(long long const a[], size_t n)
{
    auto const v = _mm_set_epi64x(0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEF, 0xBAADF00DBAADF00D);
    auto r = v;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i += sizeof(v) / sizeof(*a))
    {
        r = _mm_add_epi64(r, _mm_sub_epi64(_mm_load_si128(
            reinterpret_cast<__m128i const*>(&a[i])), v));
    }
    return r;
}
```

Notice every compiler generates memory accesses similar to this:

```
.LCPI0_0:
        .quad   -4995072469926809587            # 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d
        .quad   -2401053088876216593            # 0xdeadbeefdeadbeef
...
        movdqa  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0]
```

This is despite the fact that I'm using `_mm_set_epi64x` instead of `_mm_load_si128` for initializing my variable.

This easily trashes several data cache lines. It also feels quite unnecessary.

How can I reliably *and efficiently* get compilers to stop doing this, so that I can keep things in the instruction stream and avoid unnecessary memory accesses?

**Note:** I'm already aware I can introduce `volatile` variables to work around this, which doesn't eliminate memory accesses, but at least references stack memory instead of static data. I'm wondering if there's a better way to avoid memory accesses at all.

Comment: Forget about the compiler. What X64/SIMD instructions would _you_ emit out to be better? Once you've worked out that you can then look at how to get the compiler to do it for you. FWIW I cant see anything better than this without using a _lot_ of instruction bytes - probably way more than you are worried about here.

Comment: Most use-cases *do* want a load a constant vector from `.rodata` for non-simple constants, and `_mm_set` with constant-expression args is the idiomatic way to write that.  Two 10-byte mov-immediate instructions plus 2x `movq` + `puncpklqdq` is a lot more than 16 bytes + the length of a `movdqa` of total footprint, and L1i cache footprint can matter, too.  Note that GCC12 and later do like to use mov-immediate + movd + broadcast for repeated patterns like `_mm_set1_epi8(0x55)`, with AVX.  Before GCC14, they expand the repeat pattern to 8 bytes instead of 4! https://godbolt.org/z/1Tqdobshj

Comment: @MikeVine: `movq` + `movq` + `punpcklqdq` is one way to do it, and it's how the compiler already does it if it doesn't know the values to be constant. The difference is < 16 bytes, hardly a lot. And unlike distant memory accesses you have little control over, they're all guaranteed to be hot and available in the icache. And the situation gets even worse with `set1` intrinsics.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Unfortunately this also happens with simple constants, not just complicated ones. I merely happened to put arbitrary values in my example. Try putting `1` and you'll see the exact same problem on Clang and MSVC. (And I'm glad GCC is a tiny bit smarter, but that doesn't particularly help me here, I don't have control over the compiler.) If you have a solution for "simple" constants, I'll take that as an answer if there isn't a better one for the general case - I don't have any for that either.

Comment: Sorry yes I was wrong. You can `movq` from a `r64` to an `xmm`. So `mov r64, imm64` twice, then 2 x `movq` then a `punpcklqdq`

Comment: > How can I reliably and efficiently get compilers to stop doing this - Only by using assembler. Either write vector initialization logic as inline assembler blocks or write the entire vectorized function in assembler and compile it separately. You cannot prevent compilers from optimizing intrinsics other than by disabling optimizations completely (but even then I'm not sure you won't get a load from memory for `_mm_set_epi64x`). Even if you manage to trick the compiler into generating instructions you want by using a sequence of intrinsics, the next version of the compiler may break it again.

Comment: @AndreySemashev: How do I do that in MSVC? It doesn't support inline assembly, and out-of-line assembly wouldn't be inlined... I can't put the entire function in assembly, it'd be way too complicated and difficult to maintain. And I can understand if there's no way to "guarantee" it in the future without assembly, but is there even any way to do it *today*? I don't even have that!

Comment: P.S. @PeterCordes tangent, but interesting how GCC and Clang generate different code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/GbrT6xTaG). Seems like Clang's is slightly more expensive in that case.

Comment: @user541686: Yeah, clang's shuffle optimizer is too smart for its own good sometimes, not considering code-size for immediates.  (And sometimes using FP blends for integer vectors)  At least by now, CPUs like Core 2 and K8 where dword-granularity shuffles were slower than qword are long since obsolete, so `pshufd` is only worse by 1 byte of code-size.  Both can run on port 1 as well as 5 on Ice Lake, and same throughputs on Zen.

Comment: > How do I do that in MSVC? - Since MSVC doesn't support inline assembler, your only option is to separately compile your entire function in assembler. If you're willing to rely on the behavior of your particular compiler version, you can experiment with intrinsics trying to manually generate the constants you need. There isn't a universal pattern that I can suggest as a replacement for `_mm_set_epi64x` because depending on the surrounding code the compiler may optimize the intrinsics differently. You'll have to experiment with your code and examine the disassembler.

Comment: @AndreySemashev: Yeah, unfortunately I've actually tried doing that (all sort of weird juggling with intrinsics to generate the constants), but the damn compiler just optimizes them all away!

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to return those values from a (non-inlineable) function e.g.,

```
__attribute__((noinline))
uint64_t x() {
    return 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEF;
}
```

The only problem with this approach is that compiler can constant fold the value(e.g., `0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEF`) by 'looking-into' the returned value of the callee and simply adding `__attribute__((noinline))` may not help. It might be easier to just keep this functions in a different translation unit if link time optimizations (-flto, -flto=thin) aren't enabled.

Another approach would be to pass a buffer (thanks to @Peter Cordes for suggesting this in comment) to a function that populates the values desired by the caller. With this approach, a single function can populate all the values, compared to above where each value required a unique function. This approach also tricks the clang and gcc compilers sufficiently that it is possible to keep the function in the same translation unit by adding specific attributes.

```cpp
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include<cassert>

[[gnu::noipa]] [[gnu::optimize("O1")]] // GCC can still constant-fold at O2 and above.
[[clang::noinline]] // Clang may be able to constant-fold this in future.
[[msvc::noinline]]
void both(uint64_t a[], int N) { // N might be useful when there are more than a couple of elements
    a[0] = 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEF;
    a[1] = 0xBAADF00DBAADF00D;
}

auto foo1(long long const a[], size_t n) {
    long x[2];
    both(x, 2);

//    auto const v = _mm_set_epi64x(x[1], x[0]);  // compiles to a movdqa load anyway, or worse with clang
    auto const v = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)x);

    auto r = v;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i += sizeof(v) / sizeof(*a))
    {
        r = _mm_add_epi64(r, _mm_sub_epi64(_mm_load_si128(reinterpret_cast<__m128i const *>(&a[i])), v));
    }
    return r;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/d95fWvn16

Note: It might be helpful to add `[[gnu::const]]` if there are multiple calls to the outlined function.

Comment: Ok, that technically works for one constant, at the cost of making the I-cache and static code footprint significantly larger, and quite a bit more costly (in uops) to execute.  You could return a struct of two members (in RDX:RAX in x86-64 SysV at least), or an `unsigned __int128` to get them both from one functions.  But the x86-64 System V ABI has no call-preserved vector registers so constructing more than one vector will have to spill something to the stack.  Even for one constant, two separate calls means it needs a call-preserved register to hold one result while calling the other.

Comment: `optimize("O0")` is even more horrible; look at your GCC code-gen with `push rbp` / `mov rbp, rsp` / `pop rbp` in each function.  That does still just barely fit in 16 bytes, so aligning functions by 16 doesn't pad out to 32 bytes.  Anyway, the magic trick for GCC is `__attribute__((noipa))` for no Inter-Procedural Analysis.  https://godbolt.org/z/9GrxhbbPz

Comment: `optimize("O0")` was just to demonstrate that it works. The code can be kept in a separate translation unit with `-O3` enabled. btw, pass-by-reference will also work https://godbolt.org/z/ba4YKEfzT

Comment: Separate translation units doesn't help with `-flto`, which you normally want to enable if you care about performance.  I guess you could isolate one `.cpp` to compile with `-flto` so its functions are a black box, though.  https://godbolt.org/z/oj1ahqW7Y shows you don't need to if you can use GCC, letting you put the constants next to the code that uses them which is a very good thing for maintainability.  (IDK how to do that with MSVC).  But anyway, still, making even one non-inline function call that returns a `u128` seems like a cure worse than the disease.

Comment: If you want to take args by reference which forces a store/reload, pass a pointer to an array of 2 elements.  A store-forwarding stall is maybe less bad than 2x load + shuffle, depending on the surrounding code.  (If not, then yeah force the caller to set up two separate pointers.  Or pass a pointer to a 3-element buffer and use elements 0 and 2.

Comment: Yeah, passing pointer to a buffer seems like a better idea when there are more than a few elements.

Comment: When passing a buffer, gcc goes crazy until I add `-O1`. https://godbolt.org/z/Wh61jejY5 works for both clang and gcc.

Comment: Heh, oh right, GCC knows that for 16 bytes contiguous bytes or more, it's probably better to copy from .rodata since it saves total instructions, too.  Exactly the cost-model weights the OP was trying to defeat / work around in the first place.  https://godbolt.org/z/c4sM4aG8z passing a 3-element array works, using elements 0 and 2.

Comment: +1 I think you're on the right track with regards to separating these into sub-functions, though not regarding disabling optimizations. To prevent optimization from foiling it, I think you want `__attribute__((weak))`. I'm guessing this is probably the best answer we'll see.

Comment: Okay, so I think this is *almost* the answer, but the minimal attributes necessary here are `[[gnu::noipa]]` `[[clang::noinline]]` `[[msvc::noinline]]`, along with `[[gnu::const]]` and `[[gnu::hot]]` for optimization. So a function like `template<auto V> [[gnu::noipa]] [[clang::noinline]] [[msvc::noinline]] [[gnu::const]] decltype(V) constant() { return V; }` should work. If you want to update your answer I'll accept it; I don't imagine there's a better way.

Comment: I ended up posting my own answer actually, with some small but important tweaks. @PeterCordes: take a look, I think you might enjoy it. Thank you to everyone.

Comment: I think you've explained it more systematically in your answer. Glad to know it worked.

Comment: `_mm_set_epi64x(x[0], x[1])` has to shuffle to reverse the order of the two constants.  But clang still does a 128-bit vector load after calling the function, so it's getting the worst of both worlds: store-forwarding stall and still having to spend a `pshufd`. Use `set(x[1], x[0])` or `_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)x)`.  ( `setr(x[0], x[1])` doesn't exist for epi64x, bizarrely).  Also, `long` is a 32-bit type in the Windows x64 ABI, so you're truncating your constants there.  Use `uint64_t`, that's what it's for. https://godbolt.org/z/Tzs7GaGor

Answer (score 2):

If you want to force passing the constants via registers, you could make them parameters and force `foo` to not get inlined:

```
#ifndef _MSC_VER 
__attribute__ ((noinline))
#else
__declspec(noinline)
#endif
auto foo(long long const a[], size_t n,
 long const long dead = 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEF, 
 long const long baad = 0xBAADF00DBAADF00D)
{
    auto const v = _mm_set_epi64x(dead, baad);
    auto r = v;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i += sizeof(v) / sizeof(*a))
    {
        r = _mm_add_epi64(r, _mm_sub_epi64(_mm_load_si128(reinterpret_cast<__m128i const *>(&a[i])), v));
    }
    return r;
}
```

The default arguments of `foo` need to be seen by the caller (or you have to specify them in the header where you declare `foo`).
The caller could overwrite the constant values (you could add `assert`s to prevent that, but maybe that will make compilers optimize away the register loads in some cases).

But overall, you should probably first check how much impact loading from `.rodata` *actually* has in your case (if this is a constant, it should only be loaded once outside any loop).

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/efYGvsqKa

Comment: If this has multiple call-sites, this would bloat your program with two mov-imm64 instructions at every call site.  So it's not very scaleable to more constants, or to wider non-repeating constants, which could also end up needing to pass args on the stack especially on Windows.  (But I guess with more or larger constants, the cost analysis tips more towards letting compilers read from .rodata so you wouldn't want to use it there anyway.  Multiple constants from the same cache line are barely more expensive than 1.)

Comment: I just realized both these 64-bit constants are 32-bit repeated twice, so could be compressed down to one 64-bit number as an input for `pshufd` with `_MM_SHUFFLE(1,1,0,0)`, which is even better than separate 32-bit 2x `movd` / `shufps` `_MM_SHUFFLE(0,0,0,0)`

Comment: @PeterCordes If this is called multiple times, one could rename the function `foo_impl` and call it from a `foo` function (adding just one `jmp` instruction as overhead). Also, sure in this case this could be compressed to a single 64bit constant, but I have no idea how close this case is to what OP actually wants.

Comment: +1 I like this approach, thanks. It's not ideal, but I wouldn't be surprised if it's the best available one.

Comment: Yeah, I considered suggesting another non-inline wrapper.  That would be 2x 10-byte (mov-imm64) / 2 or 5-byte `jmp rel8/32`.  With padding of functions to 16-byte alignment, that's 32 bytes of I-cache footprint, and another taken branch for the front-end to get through.  If you're lucky it's the same I-cache line as the start of the real func. Or much worse if there weren't two register arg slots left, e.g. two pointers + a size only leaves Win x64 with one register slot, and if we need more stack args than the caller passed it won't be able to tailcall so will have to alloc new shadow space.

Comment: Btw, regarding the impact of `.rodata`, my example can be kind of misleading because it gives the impression that it's operating on a large array in a hot inner SIMD loop. In reality, not all SIMD code is like that. Sometimes `n` can be small. Or some uses might not even *have* a core SIMD loop, let alone a hot one. I know in some of my cases I use SIMD to do a bunch of arithmetic on (say) 2 or 4 numbers in parallel. Thus the cost of a cache miss can become substantial and not amortizable, depending on the workload.

Comment: You could have the real callers pass default args of `0` for two stack slots, which they could do with one `pxor`-zero / `movdqa` if they're clever, otherwise 2x `mov qword [rsp+disp8], sign_extended_imm32`, so the wrapper could replace those args and tailcall.  (Costing 2x mov to memory as well as mov-immediate).

Comment: @user541686: Another big downside to this is making the actual SIMD work non-inline so it can't optimize into the surrounding code, especially for use-cases with small `n` (especially compile-time constant), or other stuff known about pointers.  The other answer that suggests putting just the constants in a non-inline function could help more, especially with `__attribute__((const))` so the caller can still hoist the constants if there's an outer loop around this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer my own question here, because I had a realization that I think wasn't covered in the other answers.

The **first** piece of this idea is to *define a non-inlinable **identity** function*:

```
template<class T>
[[msvc::noinline]]  // or __declspec(noinline)
[[gnu::noinline]]   // or __attribute__((noinline))
[[gnu::const]]      // optimization
[[nodiscard]]
T identity_noinline(T value)
{
    return value;
}
```

You can then [pass it the constants](https://godbolt.org/z/oM1j6zMhb) before usage:

```
#include <emmintrin.h>

auto foo(long long const a[], size_t n)
{
    auto const v = _mm_set_epi64x(identity_noinline(0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEF),
                                  identity_noinline(0xBAADF00DBAADF00D));
    auto r = v;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i += sizeof(v) / sizeof(*a))
    {
        r = _mm_add_epi64(r, _mm_sub_epi64(
            _mm_load_si128(reinterpret_cast<__m128i const *>(&a[i])), v));
    }
    return r;
}
```

Observe that the generated assembly looks like the following:

```
identity_noinline:
        mov     rax, rdi
        ret
foo:
        ...
        mov     rdi, <immediate>
        call    identity_noinline
        movq    xmm0, rax
        ...
```

Not only does this code lack memory accesses, but **the `mov`s inside `identity_noinline` become register renames**—extremely fast!

On its own, this is probably sufficient. However, now you can pull another trick out of your sleeve.

The **second** piece of this idea—which is entirely optional, but perhaps useful if you're a performance freak—is to **patch the binary after linking** to remove the `call` instructions entirely!

The nice thing about using an *identity* function here (as opposed to a function that returns the constant itself, like the other answers suggested) is that it makes this insanely easy. You can just add a post-build script that simply looks for those byte patterns (`48 89 f8` in the case of `mov rax, rdi`) and replaces them after sanity-checking, because all you have to do is replace `call identity_noinline` (which is 5 bytes) with a `mov rax, rdi` (which is 3 bytes), and either pad it with NOPs, or with prefixes (e.g. I think `ds addr32 mov rax,rdi` is legal, and 5 bytes).

To sanity-check, you can assist your patcher by embedding some arbitrary assembly in the function as a "fingerprint". Easy-to-recognize stuff like `__ud2()` or `__debugbreak()` or `__nop()` or what have you, depending on your compiler.

Moreover, the fact that you have an identity function here means you *know how many such replacements to make*; it's a fixed number that you can hard-code in your script, to make sure you don't replace more than you intend. That's not really practical if every function returns a different constant.

Pulling these tricks essentially turns the `mov`/`call` sequence into 2 register renames, making them near-free.

Comment: At least for GCC/Clang, you could use `Benchmark::DoNotOptimize` instead of an actual `call` to reduce the cost in asm.  Or write your own GNU C inline asm even better suited for this like `asm("" : "+r"(v))` to "launder" a value from the optimizer, telling it that the value is an input/output operand in a register, but that it isn't `volatile` so the same input can be assumed to give the same output. And the template string is empty so no asm instructions, and not even a `"memory"` clobber.  To the optimizer it looks like a `[[gnu::const]]` function call, but with no instructions, leaf func.

Comment: If you're using inline asm anyway, you could also launder and all-ones vector constant (`"+x"(vec)` constraint for a vector reg) to trick the compiler into making good asm for things like `set1(1)` or `set1(0xFF00)` - https://godbolt.org/z/4zY1b5jxb - yup, this actually works!

Comment: @PeterCordes: Wait that's awesome. Feel free to post it as an answer, I'm happy to accept it - it seems better than mine on Clang/GCC (and I guess mine could be used on MSVC)

Comment: Hi there. It's a longstanding edit policy to remove voting/meta commentary - while upvoting other people's content is a kindness, it's not actually germane to the answer.